# How to retrieve specific column value in string format through google sheets API?

Tags: api, google-sheets-api

We have multiple columns in our google excel sheet as below,

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8dJw.png)

We are trying following API call,

[https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/7dj1kU54fgrhQk46uMrqq-W-QMlBq45kjiuEdhfjm5zE5gNvUoLk/values/'sheet1'!A2:O200?dateTimeRenderOption=SERIAL_NUMBER&valueRenderOption=UNFORMATTED_VALUE&majorDimension=ROWS](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/7dj1kU54fgrhQk46uMrqq-W-QMlBq45kjiuEdhfjm5zE5gNvUoLk/values/%27sheet1%27!A2:O200?dateTimeRenderOption=SERIAL_NUMBER&valueRenderOption=UNFORMATTED_VALUE&majorDimension=ROWS)

By hitting the above call, we get the output as below,

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpL02.png)

But, we want the value of column  `Currency` same as available in the sheet. That is `$667` where as we just get `667` by the above API call.

If we just replace the value of `valueRenderOption` with `FORMATTED_VALUE`, we get the output as below,

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jiwwd.png)

But, then it returns the value of all columns as formatted. We just want to get the value particular column as `FORMATTED_VALUE`. Is there any by which we can do this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your 1st image and 2nd 3rd images. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not - you need to make two API calls if you want different cells to have different [`ValueRenderOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption)s. This is a limitation of the API itself, as the specified `ValueRenderOption` must be the same for the whole range in a single call.